# Code Formatting for Dart not working as expected in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, dartfmt

I'm using Android Studio for Flutter development, and code formatting is not working as expected.

What could be the possible issue?

[image]

Comment: Please be more descriptive. As of now, it's difficult to answer your question properly.

Comment: I think its look good now, Thanks for edit suggestion.

Comment: Can you please post an image of the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Flutter` and check `Format code on save`.

Windows / Linux   `Ctrl + Alt + L`

MAC  `Cmd + Opt + L`

Comment: If it doesn't work (might be a bug?), try running `flutter format /path/to/file.dart` and check if you get different results.

Comment: @Anandh Krishnan I have already tried this and Its working but code not looks good as expected you can check screenshot.

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane try running `flutter format /path/to/file.dart` and check if you get different results.

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane you should not code like this, you shoud export as method, then the code will be perfectly aligned

Comment: @JustinW I tried this cmd and my path was accurate, when I attempted this, it gave me an invalid path error.

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan I have a controller where a network call is present, I am calling the controller method and handling the response, what do you mean I shall create again separate method for calling the controller method and handling response?